# Writing R extensions in C (SHMGET crash in C)

Tags: c, r, compilation, cygwin

I try to create a shared memory about cygwin in a Windows 7 environment. I compile it as normal c-program, all is working fine. If I try to call the function as R-Extension, the shmget-function is going crashed. The next step is to use semaphore. I hope this will run as well, if I solve this problem.
Is there any compiler option or something like else what I have to do? Maybe, have I to change the mingw to cygwin in R or what can I do. I'm really frustrated!

Actually I try to compile the extension with:

```
R CMD SHLIB wrappers.c IPC.c -Wall -pthread
```

And this is the problem child:

```
_smID = shmget(SHAREDMEMORYID, sizeof(struct sSharedMemory), IPC_CREAT |0666);
```

My R version:

```
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2014                        
month          04                          
day            10                          
svn rev        65387                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
nickname       Spring Dance
```

cygwin is up to date.

Comment: Have nobody any idea or a little hint?